# Moodle Login with an external Android App (Okhttp)

Tags: android, authentication, session-cookies, moodle, okhttp

Thanks for your time. Im programming an Android App for School and need a Authentification Form for the Moodle Login (Server ends with /index.php).

1. My Goal: Get the "Set-Cookie" Header in the Response with the active Cookie in it. This is given, if the Server Status returnes "303(See Other)".
2. My Question: What should I post to the Login Server, to get the Status "303" (and therefore also the right Cookie) ?

I dont know, if the ".add" Method is the right or wrong or if I should send more or less to the Server.

```
class MoodleLogin{

public static void FirstRequest(String url) throws Exception {

    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    //FORM BODY
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
               .add("username", USERNAME)  // Username
               .addEncoded("password", PASSWORT) //Passwort
               .add("token", "6f65e84f626ec97d9eeee7ec45c88303") //Security Key for Moodle mobile web service (I dont know if I need that)
               .build();

    // A normal Request
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .post(formBody) 
                        .build();

   // Asynchronous Call via Callback with onFailure and onResponse
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {

              @Override
              public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
              Log.i("Internet", "request failed: " + e.toString());
              }

              @Override
              public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) { // Server Status is not 200 - THAT IS WHAT I WANT

                            Log.d("Server Status", response.message().toString());

                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code ");

                        } else { // Server Status is 200(OK)

                            Log.d("Server Status", response.message().toString());

                        }

                        response.body().close();
                    }
              }); // End of "onResponse"

}
```

This peace of Code only returns the Server Status "200" (what is wrong in my case).
Do anyone know, what I must change to get the Status "303" ? I tested it with hurl.it (A Website for HTTP Requests) and it works only if I post the "username" and "password" like normal Parameters.

Im grateful for every answer and tip !

Comment: My Permissions: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered it myself. So here is the right code:

```
                            Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                                    .connect("your Moodle-Login Page")
                                    .data("username", username, "password", password)
                                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                                    .execute();

                            String Login_cookies = res.cookies().toString();
                            String cookie = Login_cookies.substring(1, 50);
                            System.out.println("COOKIES: "+cookie);
```